# Display Contents of Symbolic Link using NSURL

Tags: cocoa, nsurl

Example Path:

/Users/Mike/Desktop/Media

I create a Symbolic Link to the "Media" folder and name it "My Media."

That all checks out. Now I want to show the contents of the **My Media** folder to confirm the successful creation of the Symbolic Link.

A "targetField" textBox displays the correct path string with the symbolic link as the lastPathComponent:

/Users/Mike/Desktop/My Media

Prior to Mavericks the following code would show the contents of the symbolic link folder in a Finder window:

```
NSString *path = [targetField stringValue];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSArray *fileURLs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:fileURL, nil];
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] activateFileViewerSelectingURLs:fileURLs];
```

In Mavericks the code now opens the original Target folder, not the Symbolic Link folder. I realize technically the contents of both folders is the same. But the point is the code no longer reflects the Symbolic Link as the last component in the new Path. It reverts to the target folder (Media) and opens it instead.

Does my description make sense? Is there a way to make this work as it did prior to Mavericks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description doesn't make complete sense to me. "Technically the contents of both folders is the same" does not make sense, if you have a symbolic link to a folder you only have *one* folder, not two with the same contents. So I'm not sure what you're asking, but here is a guess:

Running your code under Mountain Lion opens a Finder window showing the Desktop and highlighting "My Media". To open the same window, but without highlighting you can use `openURL:` or `openFile:` on the parent folder of the path. E.g. using URLs:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path.stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
[NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace openURL:fileURL];
```

Or just with strings:

[NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace openFile:path.stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];

**Addendum**

After clarification I think what you are after is:

```
[NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace selectFile:path 
               inFileViewerRootedAtPath:path.stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
```

The method `selectFile:inFileViewerRootedAtPath:` is defined to *not* follow symbolic links. Under Mavericks this highlights the link itself.

HTH

Comment: I apologize for not being clear. I understand that if you have a symlink to a target - you only have one folder. I was referring to what you see visually if you open the target folder or the symlink folder. The contents are the same, obviously.  What I'm saying is (and you are correct) the code in Lion/Mountain Lion opens a Finder window highlighting "My Media." However - this does NOT work the same way in Mavericks. The code opens a Finder window with the target folder "Media" highlighted. I'm trying to reproduce how it works in Lion/Mountain Lion. You with me?

Comment: Thanks but still not working for me. The updated code still highlights the target, not the symlink folder - even though the new path string is accurate.(Users/Mike/Desktop/My Media).It does makes sense because you are implementing stringByDeletinLastPathComponent That's actually what I'm trying to highlight. I tried inFileViewerRootedAtPath:path. It still highlights the target folder. Can't figure it out ...

Comment: @Paul - I have tested this in 10.9.1 (the latest public release) with the same names, "Media" and "My Media", with "My Media" being a symbolic link (a) to just "Media" and (b) to the full path of "Media". In both cases the Finder opens a Desktop window and highlights "My Media" - as per the docs it does not resolve the symbolic link. (The second argument to the method is the folder the Finder should show in the window, the first argument is the item that it should highlight in that window, hence the `stringByDeletingLastPathComponent`.)

Comment: I finally got to the bottom of this. Again, thanks for the help. When I turn on Sandboxing, the problem persists. The action just will not highlight the created symLink Folder. With Sandboxing off - it works as it should. What am I missing?

Comment: @Paul - Confirmed, you've hit a YASB. Your apps console should show "sandbox extension creation failed" for something similar. From developer reports this particular error message isn't uncommon. Submit a bug report to Apple, include the info from the Console app. If you're a developer ask on the forums if anybody has figured a workaround. If you're not targeting the App Store just turn the sandbox off. BTW I tested giving temporary exceptions using both home-relative and absolute path entitlements - neither work so that's two less options for you to try. Good luck!